# How to print x amount of array per line in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm currently confused as to how to `print` x (4 in my case) amount of `array[string]` in one line and continue until there is no element left. This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Car{

public static void main(String[] args) { 

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int time,red,blue, r, b,a,c; 

System.out.println("A red car will come every 5 minutes"); 
System.out.println("A blue car will come every 7 minutes"); 
System.out.println("Please enter the time in minutes"); 

time=sc.nextInt();

blue=7; //number of minutes for blue car
red =5;  // number of minutes for red car
a= 0; // number of red cars
c= 0; // number of blue cars

r= time/red;
b= time/blue;
System.out.println("There will be "+r+" red cars");
System.out.println("There will be "+b+" blue cars");
System.out.println("Here is the order of the cars");

String[]array = new String[time];

    for(int i=0; i < time ; i++){   
      if (i % 5==0)     
      {  
       a=a+1;
       array[i]="Red";
       System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
      }

      if( i % 7==0 )    
      {  
       c=c+1;
       array[i]="Blue";
       System.out.print(" "+array[i]);}
      }

     sc.close();
   }
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough

Comment: Could you describe what your program is currently printing and compare it with what you want it to print?

Comment: I agree. It's not clear enough. Please explain it more further so we can help you easily